# Using Django 1.7's `Prefetch`

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to solve a problem using the new `Prefetch` but I can't figure out how to use it.

I have these models:

```
class Desk(django.db.models.Model):
    pass

class Chair(django.db.models.Model):
    desk = django.db.models.Foreignkey('Desk', related_name='chair',)
    nearby_desks = django.db.models.ManyToManyField(
        'Desk',
        blank=True,
    )
```

I want to get a queryset for `Desk`, but it should also include a prefetched attribute `favorite_or_nearby_chairs`, whose value should be equal to:

```
Chair.objects.filter(
    (django.db.models.Q(nearby_desks=desk) | django.db.models.Q(desk=desk)),
    some_other_lookup=whatever,
)
```

Is this possible with `Prefetch`? I couldn't figure out how to use the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use Prefetch. You only need to use Prefetch if the default prefetch_related can't do what you want.

```
Chair.objects.select_related('desk').prefetch_related('nearby_desks')\
        .filter(Q(nearby_desks=desk) | Q(desk=desk))
```

**Update**
Use Prefetch:

```
nearby_desks_qs = Desk.objects.all()

Chair.objects.select_related('desk')\
    .prefetch_related(Prefetch('nearby_desks',
                               queryset=nearby_desks_qs,
                               to_attr='nearby_desks_qs'))\
    .filter(Q(nearby_desks=desk) | Q(desk=desk))
```

Comment: I don't see where your code saves the prefetched query. I don't want it running over any of the existing attributes, I want it in a new attribute.

Comment: I'm not sure you aiming at but if you really want to use Prefetch you can checkout the update query above.

Comment: You misunderstood me. The goal of this entire thing was to have a queryset for `Desk` where every desk as an attribute `favorite_or_nearby_chairs` which contains the `Chair` queryset I specified in my original question, prefetched. I don't see how your solution provides this.